# concourse integration with azure key vault

Tags: azure-keyvault, concourse

For a cloud-native greenfield project, we are planning to use concourse.

In the project, Azure Key Vault is selected as a secret management tool and I need to integrate concourse with it. In the documentation or examples, I could not see any clue to use both.

Is there a way or workaround to integrate both?

Thanks.

Comment: I had the same requirement. Anyone on this?